# Script is not linking with the html

Tags: javascript, html

So i have this html page and somehow the script stopped working from yesterday evening to today's morning and I don't know why and im so sad, have the js in the same page as the html but it still doesn't work ! It just says that can't find functions that yesterday could do but somehow it just stop responding at every function , just like the html code is not linked with the js one but its in the same page , and even when I put the js code in the html text directly it doesn't work like no function at all and I don't think there is anything wrong , at least in the one that only redirects to the main page and even that one isn't working

```js
function mainpage() {
  window.location = "index.html"
}

function products() {
  window.location = "products.html"
}

function gotocarrinho() {
  window.location = "shopping_card.html"
}
var removeCartItensButton = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger');
console.log(removeCartItensButton.length)
for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItensButton.length; i++) {
  var button = removeCartItensButton[i]
  button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
}
var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity')
for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
  var input = quantityInputs[i]
  input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}
var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('adicionar_carrinho')
for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
  var button = addToCartButtons[i]
  button.addEventListener('clicked', addToCartClicked())
}

function string getSize() {
  var size = ""
  if (document.getElementById('xs').className = "clicked_size_button";) {
    size = xs
  }
  if (document.getElementById('s').className = "clicked_size_button";) {
    size = s
  }
  if (document.getElementById('m').className = "clicked_size_button";) {
    size = m
  }
  if (document.getElementById('l').className = "clicked_size_button";) {
    size = l
  }
  if (document.getElementById('xl').className = "clicked_size_button";) {
    size = xl
  }
  return size
}
function addToCartClicked(event) {
  var product = document.getElementsByClassName('product_name')[0].innerText
  var price = document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerText
  var size = document.getElementsByClassName('clicked_size_button')[0].innerText
  var info = [product, size, price];
  console.log(info)
  localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(info));


}


function reloadShoppingCart() {
  var storedInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("names"));
  var cartRow = document.createElement('div');
  cartRow.classList.add('rTableRow')
  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('rTable')[0]
  cartRow.innerHTML = cartRows
  cartItems.append(cartRow)
}





function quantityChanged(event) {
  var input = event.target
  if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
    input.value = 1;
  }
  updateCartTotal()

}

function removeCartItem(event) {

  var ButtonCliked = event.target
  ButtonCliked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
  updateCartTotal()

}

function updateCartTotal() {
  var cartItemContainter = document.getElementsByClassName('rTable')[0]
  var cartRows = cartItemContainter.getElementsByClassName('rTableRow')

  var total = 0


  for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {

    var cartRow = cartRows[i]
    var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
    var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('quantity')[0]
    console.log(priceElement, quantityElement)


    var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace("$", ""))
    var quantity = quantityElement.value

    total = total + (price * quantity)

  }

  total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
  document.getElementsByClassName('total')[0].innerText = "Total: " + total + "€";

}



function SizeButtonStyle(el) {




  if (el.id == 'xs') {
    document.getElementById('xs').className = "clicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('s').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('m').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('l').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('xl').className = "unclicked_size_button";


  }
  if (el.id == 's') {
    document.getElementById('xs').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('s').className = "clicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('m').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('l').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('xl').className = "unclicked_size_button";
  }
  if (el.id == 'm') {
    document.getElementById('xs').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('s').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('m').className = "clicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('l').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('xl').className = "unclicked_size_button";
  }
  if (el.id == 'l') {
    document.getElementById('xs').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('s').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('m').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('l').className = "clicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('xl').className = "unclicked_size_button";
  }
  if (el.id == 'xl') {
    document.getElementById('xs').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('s').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('m').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('l').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('xl').className = "clicked_size_button";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Nativus Clothing</title>
  <meta name="description" content="An interactive getting started guide for Brackets.">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="shop.js" async>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <nobr style="font-family:cute; color: #4a7bb5;font-weight: 600;line-height: 0;font-size: 110px;"><img src="" alt="logo" style="width:150px;height:150px;vertical-align: middle"></nobr>
  </center>
  <HR size=2 style="color: aqua"></HR>
  <button class="button" onclick="mainpage();"><b>Home</b></button>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="button" onclick="products();"><b>Produtos</b></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#" onclick="tshirt();">T-Shirts</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="hoodies();">Hoodies</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="capasmovel();">Capas de telemovel</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="button"><b>Personalização</b></button>
    <button class="button"><b>Sobre nós</b></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#" onclick="tshirt();">Empresa</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="capasmovel();">Artistas</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img class="shopping_cart_icon" src="shopping_cart.png" alt="carrinho" style="width:40px;height:40px;float:right;margin-right: 100px" onclick="gotocarrinho();">
  <HR size=2 style="color: #002366"></HR>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: On line 50 of the js file you should delete the string keyword, you dont need to specify the return type.You also should remove those ; from lines 53 - 69.

Comment: Press F12 and look in the network and console tab

Comment: I have change that and it still doesn't work

Comment: I have updated with the console

Comment: This is a typo-type issue. Please do not bother answering since we can answer in the comments. You have a "string" in of function string getSize and invalid semicolons in that function.

Comment: Also at least have `function SizeButtonStyle(el) {
    document.getElementById('xs').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('s').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('m').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('l').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('xl').className = "unclicked_size_button";

    document.getElementById(el.id).className = "clicked_size_button";
  }`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

On line no 50

1- string is not a valid return type of JS Function. Please remove it to make it work.

2- Please remove semicolon (;) as it's not valid in if the condition

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not answer typo-type questions